# Protect by password the / and /index.php but not the other scripts

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, password, httpd.conf

In the document root of my web server (Apache 2.2.15 on CentOS 6.0) I have an **/index.php** script, which I'd like to be password protected and then few helper scripts (**/helper1.php**, **/helper2.php**, ...) which actually shouldn't be password-protected - because they are sometimes used directly (for example "hotlinked" from some Excel spreadsheets).

At the moment I have every script password-protected:

```
<Location />
        AuthType basic
        AuthName "My Protected Area"
        Require valid-user

        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative  Off
        AuthLDAPURL             "ldap://ldap-server.XXX.com/OU=Users,DC=XXX,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=user)"
        AuthLDAPBindDN          afarber@XXX.com
        AuthLDAPBindPassword    XXXXXX
</Location>
```

Can anyone please suggest me a way, how to keep **/index.php** password-protected, but at the same time do not require entering a password when using **/helper1.php**, etc.?

Thank you! Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any php script you don't want to protect, put a [Satisfy Any](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#satisfy) in `Location` directive. You can also use `LocationMatch`, something like this:

```
<LocationMatch "/helper(1|2).php">
    Satisfy Any
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: No this will not protect '/' . You need a seperate one for '/' and '/index.php'. Or one combined with regexp.

Comment: No, I get authentication error immediately

Comment: Sorry, please check out my updated answer.